# VBA webscraping across multiple tables and pages of Javascript website

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have a program written in VBA which scrapes the first table of the website i am working with. I added a component for it to loop through all the items on that page by clicking the next button to view the next 50 results.

What I am having trouble with is coding which table I am referencing. My code only takes the first table on the webpage and I need all the tables but I also need the program to click through all the results.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ETFDat()

 Dim ie As Object, i As Long, strText As String
 Dim jj As Long
 Dim hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
 Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, Tr As Object, Td As Object, ii As Long
 Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object
 Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

 Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
 Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.Visible = True

  y = 1   'Column A in Excel
  z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel
 Sheets("Fund Basics").Activate
 Cells.Select
 Selection.Clear

 ie.navigate "http://www.etf.com/channels/smart-beta-etfs/channels/smart-   beta-etfs?qt-tabs=0#qt-tabs" ', , , , "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & vbCrLf

 Do While ie.busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

 Set doc = ie.document
 Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table") '.GetElementByID("tablePerformance")

 ii = 1
 Do While ii <= 17

 For Each tb In hTable

    Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
    For Each bb In hBody

        Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each Tr In hTR


            Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
            For Each Td In hTD
               ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.innerText
               y = y + 1
             Next Td
             DoEvents
             z = z + 1
        Next Tr
        Exit For
    Next bb
Exit For
 Next tb

 With doc


Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each e In elems

    If (e.getAttribute("id") = "nextPage") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next e

End With

ii = ii + 1
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Loop

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have an easier time if you called their json files and then parsed it in your VBS code.

```
http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/50/50/1
http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/50/50/2
http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/50/50/3
```

...

Comment: I've never used them before.. Is there a way to incorporate this into  my code?